# Can you travel from Switzerland to neighbouring countries on L permit residential visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, switzerland, bicycles

I will be staying Basel, Swiss on an L permit visa for the next 6 months, Im a 3rd world national. And I'm traveling to Switzerland as a dependant/ L permit.

Can I travel to neighboring countries by bicycle/ or any public transport?

Comment: People are voting to close this as off-topic because the asker is on a long-term visit to Switzerland. I disagree: the question itself is about a short-term visit to a neighbouring country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your permit appears on the [list of residence permits issued by Schengen states](https://www.udiregelverk.no/en/documents/schengen/16202010/Annex_2/).  This means that you can visit any other Schengen country while it is valid, provided that you do not spend more than 90 days in other Schengen countries in any 180-day period.  You may use any mode of transportation.